# Download Pkpass file and display in Swift

Tags: swift, passkit, pkpass

I put together a webservice that generates a pass.  When I try to download the pass I get back nil.  How do I connect my firebase cloud service  and download the pass or just convert the bufferData my server generates and convert that to something that I can pass into the PKPass.init method to generate a pass?

Download function

```
func downloadPass(completion: @escaping((Bool) -> () )) {
      self.storageRef.child("passes/custom.pkpass").getData(maxSize: Int64(1 * 1024 * 1024)) { data, error in
          if let error = error {
              print("Error downloading resource: " + error.localizedDescription)
          }
          else {
              do {
                  let canAddPassResult = PKAddPassesViewController.canAddPasses()
                  if (canAddPassResult) {
                      
                      print("Can add passes. Proceed with creating pass.")
                      self.newPass = try PKPass.init(data: data!)
                      completion(true)
                  }
                  else {
                      print("Can NOT add pass. Abort!")
                      completion(false)
                  }
              }
              catch {
                  print("Something is wrong.")
                  completion(false)
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

Upon adding `self.newPass` to my `Addpassview`, it crashes and I get back that the pass is `nil`.

```
struct AddPassView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    typealias UIViewControllerType = PKAddPassesViewController
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    @Binding var pass: PKPass?
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> PKAddPassesViewController {
        let passVC = PKAddPassesViewController(pass: self.pass!)
        return passVC!
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: PKAddPassesViewController, context: Context) {
        // Nothing goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it crash at the line with `data!`?

Comment: try using `if let data = data, canAddPassResult {...}` and remove the `!`.

Comment: @jnpdx I added the function addPassView, it fails at PKAddPassesViewController(pass: self.pass!)

Comment: `!` is inherently unsafe. You should research optional binding.